# How to solve issue – Port 8040 the connection has timed out..why?

Tags: apache, xampp, httpd.conf

I want to configure apache to listen on port 8040
I added LISTEN 8040 directive in httpd.conf

```
Listen 8040
ServerName localhost:8040
```

and assign this port number to my project in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8040>
    ServerAdmin "webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com"
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/project"
    ServerName "localhost:8040"
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and restarted the server.

but it shows this error

The connection has timed out.The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy.

same process done for port number 80

```
Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
```

it's working fine.

other port numbers not taking  why?

what else do I need to configure???? Please help.

If it matters, I use centOS server.

any help is great appreciation.

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Then vote to close it @jurgemaister

Comment: *:8040 could be rewritten to localhost:8040

Comment: @JayBlanchard I flagged it. It's all I can do.

Comment: @sitilge tried your answer but not working.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably allow port 8040 in your firewall.

Comment: i already look at that firewall,but still issue not resolved.

Comment: Did you restart your server after the changes? Also, try running `netstat -anp | grep :8040` to ensure apache is running on that port.

Comment: when i am type netstat -anp | grep :8040 this command it shows like this:
tcp6       0      0 :::8040                 :::*                    LISTEN      14859/httpd